# Converting tables from Word to Latex

Tags: texmaker, msword

I have a table in Microsoft Office which is huge and too complicated to do it again in Latex. Can I convert it to an image and then insert it in TexMaker but it is recognizable? I tried this by taking a print-screen, but the image becomes blurry. Is there another method for getting a complex table from Word to Latex?

Comment: Can't you export the table to pdf and include the pdf instead? Welcome to TeX.SX, by the way! ;-)

Comment: how can I include the pdf? I need the document to be sequential

Comment: Depending on the size, either as an graphics file `\includegraphics{youfilename}` or as `\includepdf`, using the `pdfpages` package.

Comment: i tried with the include graphics but it is blurry, I can save it as a pdf and import the pdf from latex? however I wished that the tree is sequential, i.e. it continues with the text in my latex document and not a separate page

Comment: That basically means that your table is too large if it does not fit on one single page.

Comment: it fits in a word sheet though

Comment: @user1930901 Install Libreoffice and the Writer2Latex addin. Open the Word file in Libreoffice.  Then trim out everything except the table.  Now do the export to a LaTeX file.  You will still have to do some fine tuning but all the content, etc should be there.

Comment: what do you mean by fine tuning? since if it takes a lot of time it is not worth installing etc I would just do it in Latex from scratch

Comment: @user1930901 I often have to change the table description line at the \begin{tabular}{<table description>} to get the widths I prefer. A one line rewrite. Acceptable if this is a big table.  Without knowing/seeing the specific table, exact advice is not possible. And Lazarides point is very apt.

Comment: @user1930901 It is always best from scratch and will improve your LaTeX skills

Comment: Can the table be exported as a `.csv`? What do you mean by too complicated? Just that you'd rather not do it again, or that you don't know LaTeX well enough to do it in LaTeX?  (OT: And why on earth would you compose a "complex" table in a program that isn't meant for complex tables in the first place?)

Comment: Btw, congratulations! Your question is featured in the tour page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The site http://www.tablesgenerator.com/ will generate code from a table copied and pasted from Word or Excel or a .csv. It isn't perfect, but it does a good, quick job of generating TeX code for a given table.

Comment: But it doesn't show how to do tables in LaTeX ;-)

Comment: Currently this site (which I have used previously) dumps all the table data into a single column when pasted from Excel.  I don't know why its behavior would change, but it's worthless as is.

Answer (score 6):

Your could try to copy the table to Excel and use the [Excel2LaTeX Plug-In](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex/?lang=de) to convert it to LaTeX. You will still have to put some effort into adjusting the layout. However, this will save you from having to transfer all table entries manually.